# How to store all pixel values of an image in either in an array or in a vector using matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to store all pixel values of an image in either in an array or in a vector using matlab. Please suggest me how can I do it?

Comment: `pixel_values = imread('image.jpg');`

Answer (score 0):

Probably what seems is you want to store the image in 1D, which can be done as:

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
I_1D = I(:);
```

you also take the transpose of this vector as `I_1D = I(:)';`